# Next.js 13 Context causes "Argument of type '({ children }: { children: any; }) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context<unknown>'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

When I try to useContext in my Next.js 13 app, I get the error "Argument of type '({ children }: { children: any; }) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context'."

Here is my Context store.tsx code:

```
'use client';

import { createContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState } from "react";

interface ContextProps {
    userId: string,
    setUserId: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>,
    data: object[],
    setData: Dispatch<SetStateAction<object[]>>
}

const GlobalContext = createContext<ContextProps>({
    userId: '',
    setUserId: (): string => '',
    data: [],
    setData: (): object[] => [] 
})

export const GlobalContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');
    const [data, setData] = useState<[] | object[]>([]);
    
    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ userId, setUserId, data, setData }}>
            {children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
};

export default GlobalContextProvider;
```

If you hover over "children" in the store.tsx code, I get this error: "(parameter) children: any
Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type."

Here is my root layout.tsx code:

```
import './globals.css';
import GlobalContextProvider from './Context/store';

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body>
        <GlobalContextProvider>{children}</GlobalContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Here is the page.tsx code with the error:

```
'use client';

import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import GlobalContextProvider from './Context/store';
import styles from './page.module.css';

export default function Home() {
  const { userId, setUserId } = useContext(GlobalContextProvider);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

I had to useContext within the store.tsx file. I added this to the bottom of the store.tsx file:

```
export const useGlobalContext = () => useContext(GlobalContext);
```

Then in the page.tsx file, I imported context this way:

```
import { useGlobalContext } from './Context/store';
```

And accessed it this way:

```
const { userId, setUserId } = useGlobalContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout.tsx file...
Change this:

```
import GlobalContextProvider from './Context/store';
```

To this:

```
import { GlobalContextProvider } from './Context/store';
```

Nextjs won't allow you export it like pure reactjs, so you have to do export your store.ts this way:

```
    export const GlobaContextProvider = ({ children }: any ) => {
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState('')
    const [data, setData] = useState<[] | DataType[]>([]);
    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ userId, setUserId, data, setData}}>
            {children}
        </GlobalCartContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useGlobalContext = () => useContext(GlobalContext)
```

Proceed to using it in any file like this:

```
const {userId, setUserId) useGlobalContext()
```